# jQuery-scrollTo plugin doesn't work with iPad

Tags: javascript

I have a website which is divided into several sections and I want to scroll to a specific section with the jQuery scrollTo-plugin. The website is http://www.projekt-meine-zukunft.at/?bereich=6 by the way. Now this works well with desktop pcs, but not on the iPad. Here it sometimes scrolls to the right area and sometimes it doesn't.

I use the following code:

```
if(isiPad) {

        $.scrollTo( {top: 0 , left: "8060px"} , 1, { axis:'x', easing: 'easeInOut',onAfter:function(){
            alert("ok");
        }});
    }
```

As I said, it works very well with desktop browsers, but not with iPad. Can anyone give me a tip please?

Thanks in advance,

enne